# error while saving aggregate report response in csv

Tags: jmeter, log4j, jmeter-plugins

While running the below command I am getting the log4j error. I need to save the aggregate report output in CSV format

```
PS C:\JMeter\bin> java -jar "C:\JMeter\lib\cmdrunner-2.0.jar" --tool Reporter --generate-csv "D:\Automation\Aggt_rpt.csv" --input-jtl
"D:\Automation\output.jtl" --plugin-type AggregateReport

ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console. Set system property 'log4j2.debug' to show Log4j2 internal initialization logging.
May 15, 2018 6:55:23 PM java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences <init>
WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.
```

Comment: Correct command is as below:

JMeterPluginsCMD.bat --tool Reporter --generate-csv "D:\Automation\Aggt_rpt.csv" --input-jtl "D:\Automation\output.jtl" --plugin-type AggregateReport

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ignore the `log4j2` ERROR message as since [JMeter 3.2](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-jmeter-32) there was a [change in JMeter logging subsystem](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60589) which was not adopted by all the plugins.

With regards to second `WARNING` - you can ignore it as well. Alternatively you can [re-launch the command as Administrator](https://www.howtogeek.com/194041/how-to-open-the-command-prompt-as-administrator-in-windows-8.1/)